# Images from url to listview

Tags: c#, winforms, image, listview, webclient

I have a listview which I show video results from YouTube. Everything works fine but one thing I noticed is that the way it works seems to be a bit slow and it might be due to my code. Are there any suggestions on how I can make this better? Maybe loading the images directly from the url instead of using a webclient?

I am adding the listview items in a loop from video feeds returned from a query using the YouTube API. The piece of code which I think is slowing it down is this:

```
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(query);
int i = 0;
foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
{
string[] info = printVideoEntry(entry).Split(',');
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + info[0].ToString() + "/hqdefault.jpg", info[0].ToString() + ".jpg");

string[] row1 = { "", info[0].ToString(), info[1].ToString() };
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row1, i);
YoutubeList.Items.Add(item);

imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(info[0].ToString() + @".jpg"));
imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(info[0].ToString() + @".jpg"));
}
public static string printVideoEntry(Video video)
{
  return video.VideoId + "," + video.Title;
}
```

As you can see I use a Webclient which downloads the images so then I can use them as image in my listview. It works but what I'm concerned about is speed..any suggestions? maybe a different control all together?

Comment: you should download images in a separate thread. The thread should populate the imageLists but be careful with accessing UI thread.

Comment: @Nick do you have any examples of that? This is my first time working with winforms I'm more of an asp.net type of guy lol..thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you fill info array?

Comment: @Nick just added it..hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I hope this is the code you were looking for, I can't test it since I don't have dll that you are using but I think it's OK.

```
            Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(query);

            Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart( GetImages));
            th.Start(videoFeed);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
            {
                string[] info = printVideoEntry(entry).Split(',');
                string[] row1 = { "", info[0].ToString(), info[1].ToString() };
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row1, i++);
                YoutubeList.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
        void GetImages(object arg)
        {
            Feed<Video> videoFeed = Feed<Video> arg;
            foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
            {
                string[] info = printVideoEntry(entry).Split(',');
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadFile(@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + info[0].ToString() + "/hqdefault.jpg", info[0].ToString() + ".jpg");
                ImageAdd(info[0]+".jpg");
            }
        }
        delegate void imageAdder(string imgName);
        void AddImage(string imgName)
        {
            imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(imgName + @".jpg"));
            imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(imgName + @".jpg"));
            listView1.Refresh();
        }
        void ImageAdd(string imgName)
        {
            this.Invoke(new imageAdder(AddImage), new object[] { imgName });
        }
```

Try it and I will comment it if you have some problems.

Comment: Now i take it this is still downloading every image it finds in that loop right? I as because i still see the wc.DownloadFile being called..I was wondering if I could avoid that all together by using the "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" url instead of FromFile()

Comment: Well you could make bitmap directly from stream but you should then make httprequests. The code is some kind of lazyload. Evidently listview is populated faster than the images are downloaded. I hope I helped you enough so you can continue on your own.